# I have two sign in for my app. One for server authentication and another for normal sign in. How will I inform apple that my app has two sign in?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have two sign in for my app. One for server authentication and another for normal sign in. How will I inform apple that my app has two sign in? Because in iTunesconnect we can able to enter only one sign in credential. Is there any other way. Please guide.

---

Comment: Use the Notes field.

Comment: Yes. I have mentioned in Notes only. Lets see

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow! The "Review Notes" are a great way to tell the reviewer how to "use" your app and avoid common misconceptions about your app. I've seen a lot of apps there require/have different logins or 3 or more fields to log in (think account ID & password + username).

> Additional information about your app that can help during the review process. Include information that may be needed to test your app, such as app-specific settings and test registration or account details. The Review Notes field can contain up to 4000 bytes and can be provided in any language.
>
> If your app delivers streaming video over the cellular network, enter a test stream URL in the Review Notes.
>
> This text is visible only to the Apple review team.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW6